# Creating Thread Pool without using built-in java framework

Tags: multithreading

Could anybody give idea on how to create **thread pool without using java built-in api (without Executor Class)** and will be better **if you could take example of Servlet's and write sample code explaining how multiple request's are handled through code.**

Just to inform i'v tried many article on Google but most of them talk either theory or Executor framework.

Thanks

Comment: Servlets are already managed by the Servlet container using a thread pool, you don't need to add a pool yourself. Please explain the problem you are trying to solve - possibly you are simply trying to do some academic study?

Comment: partially right..want to know how to implement thread pool, so that i can utilize in my application

Comment: So in your application where is the work coming from? There three problems to address: 1). When work arrives allocating it to a thread, 2). managing the pool of threads 3). tidying up when the work is complete. It  is easiest to talk about these when we have a context, that is when we understand where the work comes from.

Comment: it's like receiving multiple Pizza order, saving them in queue and then at later point processing them so that there will be less burden on the component taking care of processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If writing a real application I would strongly recommend using the standard Java classes. These ideas are apparently simple on the surface but the fine details of error handling and efficiency are hard to get right.

The Servlet Engine itself is effectively a thread-dispatcher, so in a Servlet we do not need to consider the processing of multiple requests, our servlet Get or Post method sees one request at a time.

So for your example I would simply use the Executor framework. If your intention is to understand the intricacies of how this could be implemented then I'd suggest looking at the [source of the Executor Framwork](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java).